# Should I use GROUPING SETS, CUBE, or ROLLUP in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We just upgraded last month to Postgres 10, so I'm new to a few of its feautures.

So this query requests that I display the days each student is taken care of and require a sum of how many students are taken care of for each weekday

```
select distinct s.studentnr,(CASE When lower(cd.weekday) like lower('MONDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end) as MONDAY,
          (CASE When lower(cd.weekday) like lower('TUESDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end) as TUESDAY,
     (CASE When lower(cd.weekday) like lower('WEDNESDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end) as WEDNESDAY,
     (CASE When lower(cd.weekday) like lower('THURSDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end) as THURSDAY,
     (CASE When lower(cd.weekday) like lower('FRIDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end) as FRIDAY,
scp.durationid

from student s

full join studentcarepreference scp on s.id = scp.studentid

full join careday cd on cd.studentcarepreferenceid = scp.id
 join pupil per on per.id = s.personid

 join studentschool ss ON ss.studentid = s.id 
 join duration d on d.id = sdc.durationid 
      AND d.id BETWEEN ss.validfrom AND ss.validuntil

where sdc.durationid = 1507
and cd.weekday is not null
order by s.studentnr
```

**where s.studentnr and cd.weekday are both varchar type**

### resulting in

[image]

However I need the following data as follows.

### Required result

[image]

Which approach is best to use in this kind of query?

### new results after change to code

```
select case grouping(studentnr)
         when 0 then studentnr
         else count(distinct studentnr)|| ' students'
       end studentnr
     , count(case lower(cd.weekday) when 'monday' then 1 end) monday
     , count(case lower(cd.weekday) when 'tuesday' then 1 end) teusday
     , count(case lower(cd.weekday) when 'wednesday' then 1 end) wednesday
     , count(case lower(cd.weekday) when 'thursday' then 1 end) thursday
     , count(case lower(cd.weekday) when 'friday' then 1 end) friday

  from mydata
 group by rollup ((studentnr))
```

order by studentnr

[image]

Nearly there I guess, just the results or values are wrong. what would you suggest I look into to correcgt the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to `ROLLUP` yourdata using a `GROUPING SET`:

```
select case grouping(studentnr)
         when 0 then studentnr
         else count(distinct studentnr)|| ' students'
       end studentnr
     , count(distinct case careday when 'monday' then studentnr end) monday
     , count(distinct case careday when 'tuesday' then studentnr end) teusday
     , count(distinct case careday when 'wednesday' then studentnr end) wednesday
     , count(distinct case careday when 'thursday' then studentnr end) thursday
     , count(distinct case careday when 'friday' then studentnr end) friday
     , durationid
  from yourdata
 group by rollup ((studentnr, durationid))
```

Which yields the desired results:

```
|  studentnr | monday | teusday | wednesday | thursday | friday | durationid |
|------------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|------------|
|      10177 |      1 |       1 |         1 |        1 |      1 |       1507 |
|     717208 |      1 |       1 |         1 |        1 |      1 |       1507 |
|     722301 |      1 |       1 |         1 |        1 |      0 |       1507 |
| 3 students |      3 |       3 |         3 |        3 |      2 |     (null) |
```

The second set of parenthesis in the `ROLLUP` indicates that `studentnr` and `durationid` should be summarized at the same level when doing the roll up.

With just one level of summarization, there's not much difference between `ROLLUP` and `CUBE`, however to use `GROUPING SETS` would require a slight change to the `GROUP BY` clause in order to get the lowest desired level of detail.  All three of the following `GROUP BY` statements produce equivalent results:

```
 group by rollup ((studentnr, durationid))
 group by cube ((studentnr, durationid))
 group by grouping sets ((),(studentnr, durationid))
```

Comment: If you provide `Create Table` statements and appropriate sample data in a delimited text format or as insert statements instead of supplying pictures of your data, then I/we can provide better help.

Comment: I've edited my response to count distinct `studentnr` values for each day instead of the non distinct numeral `1`.  Also if you are no longer including `durationid` values in the result set, you can remove the extra set or parenthesis in the `group by` clause